# How to convert the following piece of java to kotlin?

Tags: java, kotlin, apache-kafka

```
consumer.commitAsync(new OffsetCommitCallback() {
    public void onComplete(Map<TopicPartition,
    OffsetAndMetadata> offsets, Exception e) {
        if (e != null)
            log.error("Commit failed for offsets {}", offsets, e);
    }
});
```

I got the above piece of codes from definition to kafka. I have no idea how to convert them into kotlin. I tried, but failed.

Any comments welcomed. Thanks

**UPDATE**

I converted to

```
object:OffsetCommitCallback() {
  override fun onComplete(offsets:Map<TopicPartition, OffsetAndMetadata>, e:Exception) {
    if (e != null) log.error("Commit failed for offsets {}", offsets, e)
  }
}
```

but got `This class does not have a constructor`.

**UPDATE**

it seems that the following work:

```
kafkaConsumer.commitAsync(mapOf(k to currentOffsets.get(k)), object:OffsetCommitCallback {
  override fun onComplete(offsets:Map<TopicPartition, OffsetAndMetadata>, e:Exception) {
    e?.let {
      log.error("Commit failed for offsets {}", offsets, e)
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Looks like IntelliJ IDE can do this out of the box - https://www.tutorialkart.com/kotlin/convert-java-file-to-kotlin-file/

Comment: @DanW I updated my post. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like `OffsetCommitCallback` is an interface, not a class, so creating an anonymous instance of it would not use parentheses:

```
object : OffsetCommitCallback { ... }
```

rather than

```
object : OffsetCommitCallback() { ... }
```

Note also that, given that the original code is checking whether or not `e` is `null`, you probably need to use a nullable type in your Kotlin method signature:

```
override fun onComplete(..., e: Exception?)
```

Answer (score 1):

It [looks like](https://kafka.apache.org/0100/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/OffsetCommitCallback.html) `OffsetCommitCallback` is a *functional interface*, so you should be able to use a lambda in your function call ([SAM conversion](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/fun-interfaces.html#:%7E:text=With%20a%20SAM%20conversion%2C%20Kotlin,class%20that%20implements%20the%20interface.&text=A%20short%20lambda%20expression%20replaces%20all%20the%20unnecessary%20code.&text=You%20can%20also%20use%20SAM%20conversions%20for%20Java%20interfaces.)):

```
kafkaConsumer.commitAsync(mapOf(k to currentOffsets[k])) { offsets, e ->
    e?.let {
      log.error("Commit failed for offsets {}", offsets, e)
    }
}
```

Comment: @AnimeshSahu That is only true if you’re assigning it to a variable or property, not if you’re passing it to a function.

Comment: Ah got it, it infers type from function being called.